# read_excel that creates index when index_col=none using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read an excel file into a data frame and I want set the index later, so I don't want pandas to use column 0 for the index values.

By default (index_col=None), it shouldn't use column 0 of my data for the index.

How can i solve this please?

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'Indicators.xls', Header = True, index_col=None)
```

Input Excel file:

[image]

The output that I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header=None

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'Indicators.xls', Header = None, index_col=None)
```